# The missing square

Tags: logical-deduction

From a total of 9 squares, 8 are shown below. Draw the missing square.

[image: 8of9squares]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The missing one looked as such:

> ```
> ___________
> |  :      |
> |  :   ...|
> |  :   :  |
> |  :...:  |
> |_________|
> ```

Why:

> The nine squares together make up a continuous path made up of the dotted lines.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a picture:

> [image]
>  The eight given pieces make a 3x3 with a hole in the centre when you place them together so their edges match. The only possible tile that fits the hole and has a line going through all four of its quadrants is the one shown at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: How were you able to construct a 9th piece with exactly the same drawing style and coloring? It makes me think the puzzle is not an original and you were able to find the solution elsewhere?

Comment: @IvoBeckers It is just one of the corner tiles rotated.

Comment: Ah okay. that makes sense. Silly that I didn't notice that haha