# Missing rectangle

Tags: logical-deduction

Of eight 2x4 rectangles, seven are shown below and one is missing.  Which is the missing rectangle?

[image: seven of eight rectangles]

Comment: Is this to some extent a duplicate of [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112931/the-missing-square).

Comment: No it's not. That one  was dealing with squares. Here we have rectangles and other aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole set is ...

> [image: completed set]

... because it is the only way that allows ...

> to assemble the set into loops without rotation of the pieces.
>
>   [image: 8 pieces assembled into 2 loops]
>
>   PS:  Or, with rotations, assemble loops in a square.
>
>   [image: Pieces assembled in a square]

Comment: You got the missing rectangle but the assembly is not correct. I'll accept in anyway.

Comment: The last is the correct assembly.